# Different sheet pasting

Tags: vba, excel, row

I have written a code which gives me the errors (if any cell is non numeric) in a separate sheet called "Error_sheet".

But the output is a bit clumsy as it gives me non numeric cell address in a confusing fashion. Like the errors will not be pasted one after another. There will be some blanks in between if there are more than one non Numeric cells.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If IsNumeric(Range("A" & i).Value) Then

        Else
            Sheets("Error").Range("A" & Row).Value = "Error in" & i & " row of ColumnNAme"
            Row = Row + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

It gives me output like shown below but can I get the output like Error in 7,14 rows of column name in a desired cell of "Error_sheet".

[![Output][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqXwq.png

Comment: avoid calling a variable simply Row. Row is a range object. Use option explicit at the top of your code and then you will have to declare and assign Row before incrementing. Also, a picture of your data alongside the result would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of what you've written is that you want something like this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

' Unqualified book/sheet below, means code will always run the isnumeric check on the cells of the active sheet. Is that what you want? '

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 

Dim Index as long
Dim i As Long
Dim NonNumericRows() as string
Redim NonNumericRows(1 to lastrow)

For i = 2 To LastRow

If not(IsNumeric(Range("A" & i).Value)) Then
Index = index + 1
NonNumericRows(Index) = cstr(i)
End if

Next i

Redim preserve NonNumericRows(1 to index)

Sheets("Error").Range("A1").Value = "Error in row(s): " & strings.join(nonnumericrows,", ") & " of ColumnNAme"

End Sub
```

Hope it works or helps.

Answer (score 0):

Like QHarr suggested, using `Option Explicit` is normally a good idea, and try not to use VBA operators as variables.

Also when working with more than 1 sheet, its best to define each in the code. I dont know what your first sheet is called, so please change the line: Set `shSource = Sheets("Sheet1")` to suit:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SubErrorSheet()
    Dim lr As Long, i As Long
    Dim shSource As Worksheet, shError As Worksheet

    Set shSource = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set shError = Sheets("Error")
    lr = shSource.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lr
        If Not IsNumeric(shSource.Range("A" & i).Value) Then
        shError.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "Error in row " & i & " of ColumnNAme"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```